# How to consolidate multiple code lines using list comprehension

Tags: python

I'm writing a small function to parse csv file. The following code is supposed to retrieve the line and create dictionary key from the header. There is a list comprehension used in the third line in the loop. Is there a way all of the lines after for statements can be consolidated into fewer line and write into condensed code. For e.g. list comprehension

```
f = open("test.csv")
for line in f:
   a = line.split(",")
   b = [i.replace('"', '').replace('\n', '') for i in a]
   header = {n:[] for n in b[1:]}
```

Comment: Beside the point, but you don't need to roll your own CSV parser. There's a [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

I would go as is since condensing more would make the code less readable. I think that

```
b = [i.replace('"', '').replace('\n', '') for i in line.split(",")]
header = {n:[] for n in b[1:]}
```

Should work. That is, if you really need to implement such function, because it is readily available through many modules such as `csv` and `pandas`

**Advice**: don't use `f = open("test.csv")`. Instead, use the `with` statement:

```
with open("test.csv") as f:
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the csv module for easier file reading, hopefully this will work:

```py
import csv
with open("test.csv", "r") as f:
    header = {n:[] for n in csv.reader(f)}
```